# If I was going to or If I were going to

Tags: grammar, if

In response to "If you were going to start a company, what would you do?" what should be the correct answer between the following two---

> 1. If I was going to start a company, I would...

or

> 2. If I were going to start a company, I would...

Comment: See tchrist's excellent answer on "*if I was* vs *if I were*" [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/429514/365490)

Answer (score -1):

Both the sentences are imaginary sentences i.e. something which has not happened in the past neither is it going to happen in future. But still you are thinking about it. So that's just an imagination.

But the first sentence suggests that it might have possible for you to start a company. So it was a bit closer to reality.

But the second sentence is extremely fantasized. This kind of imagination is not even remotely possible to be manifested in reality.

Let's consider this example -

If you are asking some students in the school to write an essay, then what are titles of topic you would give to them?

```
1. What if I were a bird
2. What if I were the president
3. What if I were a mountain

Notice that these sentences will never become reality in life. They are just testing your imagination power and nothing else.
```

Now let's see these examples

```
1. What if I was going to the party that night
2. What if I was to tell your secret to her
3. What if I was to start a new business

Notice these sentences are very close to reality. That is why it is not possible to use 'were' in these situations. Because using 'were' would imply that even these things will never become reality.
```

Comment: I would just note that many native speakers will never say *if I were...,* so it's entirely likely for *if I was....* to be used in both senses.  Furthermore, the traditional subjunctive *if I were* actually can be used with something that is within the realm of possibility, and speakers who use it would use it in the second set of examples.  It is for that reason that I have downvoted the answer.